# Instagram Oauth URL giving page not available

Tags: php, oauth, instagram-api

I'm trying to access the Instagram feeds for a web app and the first step is registering an app(which I've done already). I'm trying implicit authentication by redirecting the user the following URL

https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=a483b7ac9c264fb0a6b04c69edc9a6e9&redirect_uri=thatbrowngentleman.com/instag/insta.php&response_type=token

Going to that link yields

> Sorry, the page isn't available.

At this point, I have no idea why. In my instagram developer's account the app is registered as followed:

```
CLIENT INFO
CLIENT ID   a483b7ac9c264fb0a6b04c69edc9a6e9
CLIENT SECRET   *HIDDEN-ON-PURPOSE*
WEBSITE URL http://thatbrowngentleman.com/instag/insta.php
REDIRECT URI    thatbrowngentleman.com/instag/insta.php
SUPPORT EMAIL   *Hidden for privacy*
```

The parameters in the verification URL seems to match the one's in my developer's account. I am surprised I'm still getting a broken link. I would really appreciate if somebody here could ignore my naivety and help me with it.

Comment: That link is actually working for me as of now, probably just a temporary issue?